# Access to User records in Flow run from Portal Site (different behavior between PRD and Sandbox)

Tags: permissions, guest-user, portal

We have a Screen Flow that is embedded in a public Site that allows users to sign up for an account. The flow runs as "System Context Without Sharing--Access All Data". As part of the flow, we do a query on the User object with some criteria to determine if they already exist in our system and take them down a different path if so. This Flow has worked and continues to work as expected in our PRD environment.

We recently refreshed our Full-Copy Sandbox (STAGE) from PRD and the Flow can no longer find existing User records when accessed through the Site page. When running the Flow in Debug mode, it works as expected (even when running as the Guest Portal User). This would seem to indicate there is some permissions setting that is different in STAGE vs. PRD. We have not made any changes to the flow or permissions in our STAGE environment and both PRD and STAGE are on the same Salesforce version (Winter '23)

The only thing we have found is that the following query in Stage returns 2 results, vs 0 results in PRD. Again, we haven't explicitly changed any of these values:

```
SELECT Id,Classification, Description, DeveloperName, EnforcementType, MasterLabel, RecordFilter, NamespacePrefix, TargetEntity, UserCriteria, IsActive
FROM FieldRestrictionRule
```

In both environments, User Management Settings are the same. The PRD environment has an option not available in Stage, Hide Personal Information, that is Enabled (again, they are both on Winter '23). In both, Enhanced Personal Information Management is disabled.

Any help would be appreciated on this. Salesforce support has not really been able to tell us what the cause of the different behavior is.

Comment: if you have access to a vendor devops tool (e.g. Gearset, Copado, ...) you could do a compare of the guest user profile between prod and sandbox

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Just used Data Loader to export Profiles from the two environments and didn't see any differences.

Comment: Any updates on this issue ? We are also facing the same issue between 2 sandboxes.

Comment: No updates. We are still working with Salesforce support to try and figure out the issue.

Comment: Have you set a debug log in your full sandbox with Workflow = Finer level?

Comment: This turned out to be a bug on the Salesforce side. See the following: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002d7RMQAY.  It sounds like it was a new runtime version of Flows that was enabled in our org.